# Static rewrites for ASP.NET MVC and II7, why all the page links break?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, url-rewriting

With the following settings in the `Web.Config` file, when the visitor uses `www.domain.com/company/openposition` all the page links become broken.

```
<rule name="Rewrite Rule">
   <match url=".*" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" />
</rule>

<rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
   <add key="/company/openposition" value="/Careers" />
</rewriteMap>
```

If the page contains the following link...

```
<a href="/Careers/Graphics">Read full job description</a>
```

...it becomes (the same thing I see on the browser URL bar):

```
<a href="/company/Careers/Graphics">Read full job description</a>
```

And the result after clicking it is a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax, you need to use type as `Redirect`, not `Rewrite`:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```